Integration test: ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request Server redirected too many times
I try to write integration test, but it keep on failing. this time it's error is about redirecting
O error on GET request for "http://localhost:43331/findAllUser": Server redirected too many  times (20)
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:43331/findAllUser": Server redirected too many  times (20)
at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:915)
at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:895)
at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:790)
at app//org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:431)
at app//org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate.getForEntity(TestRestTemplate.java:244)

I wrote the intergation test with testcontainer as replacement of mysql and TestRestTemplate for rest api. This is my integration test:
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class UserServiceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @Container
    static MySQLContainer<?> mysql = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:latest");

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        mysql.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        mysql.stop();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void configureTestProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mysql::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mysql::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mysql::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto",() -> "create");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void afterEach(){
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void happyPath_findAllUser_integrationTest() {
        ResponseEntity<UserEntity[]> response = testRestTemplate.getForEntity("/findAllUser", UserEntity[].class);
        assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

I also have SSL setup that might cause the redirecting http to https:
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requiresChannel(channel -> channel.anyRequest().requiresSecure()) // redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .formLogin(login -> login.disable())
                .httpBasic(httpBasic -> httpBasic.disable());
        return http.build();
    }
}

and the config of it at application.properties:
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=keystorepassword
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsignedcertificate

Update: I commented out all of the SSL configuration and the test passed without problem. How can I configure it so it would also pass with SSL configuration?

There seems to be an infinite redirection loop.
Please first test the server with powershell cmdlet 'invoke-webrequest' if possible such as;
$A = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://abc.lab/getreq1" - 
     MaximumRedirection 0)

You probably will see an error containing the following phrase:
"...Maximum Redirection Exceeded..." . 

Still $A instance is not null and can be queried as follows for the 'location' property of the instance;
$A.Headers.Location

This location property will provide the first location to be that server will redirect the request to, but the request was not redirected is not expected in the above command as we intentionally set maximumredirection parameter to zero:
Similarly when you increment the maximumredirection parameter by 1 in the powershell command you may see the location of the second location that the request would be redirected to;
$ B = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://abc.lab/getreq1" - 
      MaximumRedirection 1)

If you check the location property, this will provide http(S) URL that                                                                                                                                                                                        is to be redirected the next time
$B.Headers.Location: 
http://abc.lab/getreq1

This means that the infinite loop is caused by redirection first occurs to https:// then redirection occurs again to the http:// meaning there seems to be an infinite loop hence 'too many redirects' error occur.
Probably you will find a similar recurrent redirection pattern that causes an infinite redirection loop in your case.
Then you may run a trace on the server side. For ex. if this is an IIS server you may setup 'Failed Request Tracing' and run the get request again and see the traces for the modules that participate on redirection.

sorry, but I don't use windows. my OP is debian-linux. With Swagger everything is fine, and when I use Curl -k, everything is fine as well. (the curl throws "(60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate" without -k)

the curl that I am trying and I get the positive answer is: curl -X 'GET' -k 'https://localhost:8443/findAllUser'

You may add the self-signed certificate to the 'Trusted Root Store' of the client browser OS . Then pls run curl without -k option.

I prefer not to change the trusted root store of browser. I disabled the self-signed certificate and the integration test run fine. but I am still wondering how can I have both self-signed certificate with integration test running fine

If a method the that allows certificate chain check to be disabled you may use this. For example: curl has -k option
